# Install ADT plugin on Aptana 3

Tags: aptana, adt

Is there a way to install android development tool plugin on aptana 3? I'm trying to install the plugin on aptana instead of eclipse according to this tutorial http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing but I get the error message on 6th step:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Traceview 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You need to install JDT tools for Aptana

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Installing+the+Java+Development+Tools

Follow this tutorial to install JDT, then you can install ADT

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help > Install New Software > Click on the link "*Available Software Sites*" bellow the "Add" button  >  Click on "Eclipse Helios Update Site"  >  OK.

This worked for me.

Comment: This was the easiest solution.  Just enable the update site for your version (Helios?  Indigo for me), and it can resolve any dependencies.